# Get a textbox id inside a div in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need your help to find textbox id inside a div based on div's css class name in jquery.

```
<div class="FH_element FH_text required" id="FH_0_first_name">
    <label for="FHE_0_first_name">First*<small></small></label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" title="" name="first_name" value="" tabindex="3" id="FHE_0_first_name">
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code i need to find the textbox id(FHE_0_first_name) using div's class name(required)..in jquery.

Answer (score 8):

Using very specific selectors:

```
var textboxId = $('div.FH_element.FH_text.required')
    .find('input[type="text"]')[0]
    .id;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
jQuery('.required input').attr('id')
```

Answer (score 4):

This should help

```
var textBoxId = $('.required').find('input[type=text]').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('.required').find('input').attr('id')
```

Comment: Thanks for responding and helping